# Use of landscape and pdflscape packages with spanish package

Tags: spanish, pdflscape, lscape

I tried `lscape` and `pdflscape` packages with `spanish` package.
It doesn't work, only with english package.
Are there any solution? I want to have the list of tables and the date in spanish, but I can't  use those packages.
This doesn't work for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{Blah }
\usepackage{spanish}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Matrix table}\verb+-+
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{35mm}|p{42mm}|p{42mm}|p{42mm}|p{42mm}|}
\hline \rowcolor{Gray}
\centering \textbf{TITLE} & \centering \textbf{TITLE} & \centering\textbf{TITLE} & \centering\textbf{TITLE} & {\centering\textbf{TITLE}}\\[0.5ex]
\hline
text & text & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text & text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

But, if I change the spanish package by english, it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you put together a tiny document that shows the problem you're having and add that to your question? See [I've been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2693).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spanish` package is not a package you load using `\usepackage` but instead is an option that you pass to the `babel` package.  So the correct usage should be:

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

NOT `\usepackage{spanish}` Your document should have put up the following error:

> ```
> You have used an old interface to call babel.
> You may expect compatibility problems wit other packages. 
> You could proceed but don't complain if you run into errors.
> ```

One other comment about your code. I'm not sure what the `\verb+-+` line is supposed to do for you. If you want to change the spacing or format of the caption, you should use the `caption` package.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it was a headache. It works. About the `\verb+-+`, I used to solve the small space between table and its caption; but I find the solution with the `caption` package. Thanks for all!